# How does the close vote count increase as my flag weight increases?

Tags: support, vote-to-close, flag-weight

The [vote-to-close privilege page on Super User](https://superuser.com/privileges/close-questions) states the following (emphasis added):

> You may cast up to 24 close votes per day. (This ceiling **increases dependent on your flag weight** and is set at a default of 50 on Stack Overflow.)

How does this limit increase as my flag weight increases?  I haven't received more than 24 votes to close in spite of a high flag weight on SU (673.8296 as of the time of this post).

Comment: Perhaps 50 is the maximum *only on Stack Overflow?*

Comment: 50 is not the maximum on _Stack Overflow_; it's the default value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the various sites where I can vote to close, the number of close votes is 24 regardless of flag weight, except on Stack Overflow where it's 50 regardless of flag weight.

All privilege descriptions are synchronized from [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges), where they're editable by any user with 2000 rep on MSO. I've corrected the [close vote privilege page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/close-questions).

Answer (score 2):

The maximum amount of close votes on most SE sites is 24, as the description says. Stackoverflow is the exception with 50 close votes.

I checked my accounts with close privileges and I have 50 on Stackoverflow and 24 everywhere else, which confirms this interpretation of the privilege page.

On the dependence on flag weight I'm not sure, I got 50 close votes on SO with only 160 flag weight.